# intersection of two class definition

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, pellet

classes `a` and `b` are defined as follows:
[image]

[image]

as you see both classes have the axiom :`prop2 some rdfs:literal`
I need to define class `c` based on `a` and `b` (e.g by using `and` , `or`, `not`) so that has this axiom as its definition.

Comment: As prop2 will be commun to all 3 subclasses, why don't you make it a prop of owl...
Then a,b and c wil inheratite it. And idk which language you're using, but in python you can do a classes based in two classes `class c (a, b):`

Comment: @SaulVP That's not a useful approach in OWL.

Answer (score 1):

You could define `c` as `a and b` - because the class `prop2 some rdfs:Literal` will always belong to the intersection of the two classes.

However it would be a lot more intuitive to declare `c` subclass of `prop2 some rdfs:Literal` and then `a` subclass of `c` and `b` subclass of `c`. Is there a reason that forces you to define `c` in terms of `a` and `b` and not the opposite?

Comment: Classes a and b each one has many axioms.i need to find the same axioms of them